# How to use Boostrap DateTimePicker in ASP.Net Web Form

Tags: jquery, asp.net, bootstrap-4, datetimepicker

I am trying to use a Bootstrap `datetimepicker` in my Asp.Net web form. No errors are being thrown but the calendar never fires when I click on the icon. How can I get this to work in Asp.Net? Since this is not an asp: control, I'm not making an `_onClick()` function in my C#, but do I need to make one in my `<script></script`? Here's what my code looks like:

```
<link href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.9.1/themes/start/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" />
...
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.6/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function() {
        $(function() {
            $('#uxDateTimeLocalTextbox').datetimepicker();
        });
    });
</script>
<body>
....
    <div class="container">
      <div class='col-md-5'>
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class='input-group date' >
            <input type='text' class="form-control" id="uxDateTimeLocalTextbox" value="" runat="server"/>
            <span class="input-group-addon">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
            </span>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Are you getting any error in web browser console? Also I am seeing that you should write your HTML as in the examples or the datepicker js won't work. (You have to put the same classes and attributes in your HTML elements)

Comment: I am not getting any errors in my web browser. When you say "you should write your HTML as in the examples", can you elaborate? This code is from an example; the only thing I added was `id="uxDateTimeLocalTextbox" value="" runat="server"` in the input. I have to use an id, value, and runat in order to extract the value from the input and send it to my SQL SP as a parameter in my C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set the  ClientIDMode to "Static"

```
<input type='text' class="form-control" id="uxDateTimeLocalTextbox" value="" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" />
```

by default webforms change the rendered html id. clientidmode changes that behavior.

Comment: Yep that did it!. The whole reason I needed this was to be able to out populate the input with a value from a SQL SP and that worked too! Thanks for the assist.

Answer (score 1):

```
Please try this code    
<div class="row">
     <label class="col-md-4 control-label">  From Date</label>
 <div class='input-group ' id='FromDate' data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy"  style="width: 132px;">
  <input type='text' class="form-control" id="txtFromDate"  onchange="txtFromDate_change();" />
   <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="fa fa-calendar fa_cal"></span></span>
   </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#FromDate").datepicker({
      autoclose: true,
      todayHighlight: true,
      orientation: 'auto bottom'
     }); 
});
</script>
```