# DateTimePicker doesn't appear in toolbox

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

As the title says. I am using Visual Studio 2019 and in my toolbox DateTimePicker doesn't appear. Is this due to a change in the tools name or is there some reason my tool isn't showing?

Perhaps another way to enter the DateTime if I can't get it?

Comment: Ah I see. I wasn't aware of that Hans, thank you. I'm new to VS. I believe my application is an ASP.NET Web Application.

Comment: Maybe something like this to compare your code to make help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55226181/how-to-use-boostrap-datetimepicker-in-asp-net-web-form